# What kind of power supply is this?(using an NPN as regulator and Buck converter)

Tags: power-supply, transistors, bjt, buck, npn

I have one of this FM Modulator and use it in my car as MP3 player.

[image: image1]

Currently it doesn't work and I opened it to know what's going on inside it and saw this ridiculous supply:

[image: image2]

[image: images3]

As you see there is just a [MJE13003](http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/172427/ONSEMI/MJE13003/217/1/MJE13003.html) transistor. interesting. I expected to see something like 7805 not a BJT. How does this power supply work?

Source of images: [link](http://wasp.kz/articles.php?article_id=987&rowstart=0)

Add:

Another images:

[image: image4]

[image: image5]

Comment: Maybe just an emitter follower buffering a zener diode reference.  A cheap linear regulator.

Comment: If I had to guess (and I do, because you didn't bend up the BJT nor take the right angles in the pictures), the diode is a zener and the BJT is operating as an NPN emitter-follower. (Cripes. Just now noticed JohnD's response -- page didn't update while typing. So we agree.)

Comment: @jonk Two images added.

Comment: @Roh Still can't see what the traces do underneath that "big black thing." But it still looks like an emitter follower and I still think the diode is a zener.

Comment: Silk screen clearly indicates 5V, so I assume it is a 5V LDO once made by Fairchild.  You can replace that with a similar one if you aren't getting 5V

Comment: but the diode or zener and 101R are on the ground side for reverse battery charge error protection. so the 0V is not the same as the car battery 0V. The antenna signal is C coupled to 12V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a zener regulating emitter follower like this: -

[image]

C1 is across the input and C2 is across the output.